# angularjs : change which variables to watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to change which variables to watch.

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainController', 
  function($scope) {
    
    $scope.current = null;
    $scope.select = function(item) {
      $scope.current = item;
    };
    
    var watch = ['current'];
    $scope.$watchGroup(watch, function() {                 // This does not work
      if ($scope.current !== null) {
        watch = ['current'];
        Array.prototype.push.apply(watch, $scope.current.watch);
        $scope.current.callBack();
      }  
    });
    
    $scope.list = [
        {
          name: 'test-A',
          watch: ['a'],
          callBack: function() {
            $scope.value = 2 * $scope.a;
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'test-B',
          watch: ['b'],
          callBack: function() {
            $scope.value = 3 * $scope.b;
          }
        }
      ];
  
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
      {{current != null ? current.name : 'DropDown'}}
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li ng-repeat="item in list">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="select(item)">{{item.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  When "test-A" is selected, result is 2 times of A.
  <br> When "test-B" is selected, result is 3 times of B.

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>A</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>B</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="b">
    </div>
  </form>

  <br> result : {{value}}
  <br>
</body>

</html>
```

[This](https://plnkr.co/edit/IFpqwPUUF9xEJSLk83VT?p=preview) is Plunker example.

The `result` should be 2 times of `A` when `test-A` is selected, should be 3 times of `B` when `test-B` is selected.

I would like to update which variables to be watched. But the way shown in the line `This does not work` does not work. This `$watchGroup` only fires when `current` is changed. I would like to fire this `$watchGroup` when `current` or `a` is changed in case `test-A` is selected, and when `current` or `b` is changed in case `test-B` is selected.

I know `$scope.$watchGroup(['a', 'b', 'current'], ...` works. But I do not like to fire this `$watchGroup` when `test-A` is selected and `b` is changed and vice versa.

How can I update which variables to be watched?

Answer (score 1):

> Change the line:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(watch, function() {
```

as below:

```
$scope.$watch('current', function() {
```

The reason behind this is the `current` value is changed when you clicked on menu. `var watch = ['current'];` is different variable and this one is not changed when you click on menu. To work properly `watch`, you need to point to the correct variable, in your case, `$scope.current` is the correct variable.

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainController', 
  function($scope) {
    
    $scope.current = null;
    $scope.select = function(item) {
      $scope.current = item;
    };
    
    var watch = ['current'];
    $scope.$watch('current', function() {
      if ($scope.current !== null) {
        watch = ['current'];
        Array.prototype.push.apply(watch, $scope.current.watch);
        $scope.current.callBack();
      }  
    });
    
    $scope.list = [
        {
          name: 'test-A',
          watch: ['a'],
          callBack: function() {
            $scope.value = 2 * $scope.a;
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'test-B',
          watch: ['b'],
          callBack: function() {
            $scope.value = 3 * $scope.b;
          }
        }
      ];
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
      {{current != null ? current.name : 'DropDown'}}
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li ng-repeat="item in list">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="select(item)">{{item.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <br>

  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>A</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>B</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="b">
    </div>
  </form>

  <br> result : {{current.watch}}
  <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this does not work as I hope. I would like to fire the `watch` when `a` is changed in case `test-A` is selected, and fire when `b` is changed in case `test-B` is selected.

Comment: Check the updated code snippet. If you need other thing, let me know

Comment: Sorry this also does not work as I hope. I would like to update the `result` value when the value `A` (in case `test-A` selected) or `B` (in case `test-B`) is changed

Comment: In which field you want to update, input box? What is the meaning of "When "test-A" is selected, result is 2 times of A.
  When "test-B" is selected, result is 3 times of B." And if test-A selected 2 times then what is expected?

Answer (score 1):

find the following code as your answer see if it helps you.

**Script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainController', 
  function($scope) {

    $scope.current = null;
    $scope.select = function(item) {
      $scope.current = item;
    };

    var watch = ['current'];
    $scope.$watchGroup(watch, function() {
      if ($scope.current !== null) {
        watch = ['current'];
        Array.prototype.push.apply(watch, $scope.current.watch);
        $scope.current.callBack();
      }  
    });

    $scope.list = [
        {
          name: 'test-A',
          watch: [' is two times of a'],
          callBack: function() {
            $scope.value = (2 * $scope.a) + ($scope.current.watch);
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'test-B',
          watch: [' is three times of b'],
          callBack: function() {
            $scope.value = (3 * $scope.b) + ($scope.current.watch);
          }
        }
      ];

});
```

I just concatenated `($scope.current.watch)` this with your result

See if it forked to your plnkar.

https://plnkr.co/edit/UGPe4lgJPydEeAXOc0xR?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this does not work as I hope. I would like to fire the `watch` when `a` is changed in case `test-A` is selected, and fire when `b` is changed in case `test-B` is selected.